# matplotlib subplots very slow

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, data-visualization

The following code

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from defect_segmentation.data_loading.DatasetSingleImage import dataset_single_image_default
import numpy as np


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def main():
        dataset = dataset_single_image_default()
        batch_size = 16
        shuffle = True
        num_workers = 0
        loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, num_workers=num_workers)
        for i_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(loader):
            fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(np.sqrt(batch_size)), batch_size // int(np.sqrt(batch_size)))
            fig.suptitle(f"i_batch = {i_batch}")
            for i_sample, ax in zip(range(sample_batched.shape[0]), axs.flat):
                ax.set_title(f"Sample #{i_sample}")
                ax.axis("off")
                ax.imshow(sample_batched[i_sample, :, :])
                plt.pause(0.001)

    main()
```

works and outputs figures like so

[image]

This is fine.

Problem is by the 10th figure, it becomes very slow to populate the figures. I don't know what can be causing this.

---

For completeness, here is the code for creating the dataset (striding over a single image):

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from Utils.ConfigProvider import ConfigProvider
import cv2
import os
from overrides import overrides # pip install overrides


class DatasetSingleImage(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_path: str, sample_shape: tuple, strides: tuple):
        self._path = image_path
        assert os.path.isfile(self._path)
        self._im = cv2.imread(self._path)
        self._shape = self._im.shape
        self._rows, self._cols = self._shape[0], self._shape[1]

        self._sample_shape = sample_shape
        self._sample_rows, self._sample_cols = self._sample_shape[0], self._sample_shape[1]

        self._strides = strides
        self._stride_rows, self._stride_cols = self._strides[0], self._strides[1]
        # self._rows_start_range = range(0, self._rows, self._stride_rows)
        # self._cols_start_range = range(0, self._cols, self._stride_cols)

        self._rows_tuples_range = \
            [(c, min(c + self._sample_rows, self._rows)) for c in range(0, self._rows - self._sample_rows, self._stride_rows)]
        self._cols_tuples_range = \
            [(r, min(r + self._sample_cols, self._cols)) for r in range(0, self._cols - self._sample_cols, self._stride_cols)]

        self._n_strides_rows = len(self._rows_tuples_range)
        self._n_strides_cols = len(self._cols_tuples_range)
        self._total_strides = self._n_strides_rows * self._n_strides_cols

    def __len__(self):
        return self._total_strides

    @overrides # pip install overrides
    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        row_ind = ind // self._n_strides_cols
        col_ind = ind % self._n_strides_cols
        sample_x = self._rows_tuples_range[row_ind]
        sample_y = self._cols_tuples_range[col_ind]
        sample = self._im[sample_x[0]:sample_x[1], sample_y[0]:sample_y[1]]
        assert sample.shape[:2] == self._sample_shape
        return sample


def dataset_single_image_default():
    path = ConfigProvider.config().data.defective_inspected_path1
    sample_shape = (50, 50)
    strides = (25, 25)
    dataset = DatasetSingleImage(path, sample_shape, strides)
    return dataset
```

---

**What is making the plotting slow, and how to fix it?**

Comment: do you close the figure after every batch? if all the figures are still "active" - this can significantly slowdown your machine. Try writing the figures to disk (using e.g. [`savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)) and close them after every batch. Does this affect speed ?

Comment: @Shai That was it. Can you explain why that is the case? Is there a workaround to keep figs open?

Comment: an open figure (window) takes some system resources. if you have many open windows this amounts to a lot of system resources... @Gulzar

Comment: @Shai This actually makes no sense to me, because Windows can easily handle 20+ windows, but the slowness comes at around 10 figures.

Comment: it's not just the window - it's all the graphic elements: axes, titles, legends etc.

Comment: @Shai Ok, that would imply the problem is inherent to matplotlib. Maybe all the windows are on the same process with the same GIL? And if so, is there a workaround?